How can I form groups by a mask and N rows after that mask?
My DataFrame is:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, False],
    }
)

Expected output is forming groups like this:
        a
1    True
2   False
3    True

        a
5    True
6   False
7    True

      a
8    True
9   False
10  False

The logic is:
Basically I want to form groups where df.a == True and two rows after that. For example, in order to create the first group, the first True should be found which is row 1. Then the first group is rows 1, 2 and 3. For the second group the next True must be found which is not in the first group. That row is row 5. So the second group is consisted of rows 5, 6 and 7. This image clarifies the point:

And this is my attempt that didn't work:
N = 2
mask = ((df.a.eq(True))
        .cummax().cumsum()
        .between(1, N+1)
        )

out = df[mask]


Since you problem is inherently iterative, you must loop.
The most straightforward option IMO is to use a simple python loop:
def split(df, N=2):
    i = 0
    a = df['a'].to_numpy()
    while i < len(df):
        if a[i]:
            yield df.iloc[i:i+N+1]
            i+=N
        i+=1

out = list(split(df))

Output:
[       a
 1   True
 2  False
 3   True,
        a
 5   True
 6  False
 7   True,
         a
 8    True
 9   False
 10  False]

If you want a simple mask and a unique DataFrame as output, you could improve the speed with numba:
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def get_indices(a, N=2):
    i = 0
    out = []
    while i < len(a):
        if a[i]:
            out.extend([True]*(N+1))
            i += N+1
        else:
            out.append(False)
            i += 1
    return out[:len(a)]

out = df.loc[get_indices(df['a'].to_numpy())]
out['group'] = np.arange(len(out))//3

Output:
        a  group
1    True      0
2   False      0
3    True      0
5    True      1
6   False      1
7    True      1
8    True      2
9   False      2
10  False      2

Timings for N = 2

relative timings:

Timings for N = 100
NB. @Triky's solution is not providing correct results here

relative timings


I defined a function mask_dataframe which takes in the DataFrame and returns groups of length mask_len + 1 in a new DataFrame by looking for the first instance where of True and pulling out the next mask_len items.
The last value is used to skip over True elements that have already been aggregated into the new df.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, False],
    }
)


def mask_dataframe(df: pd.DataFrame, mask_len: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    last = 0  # keep track of which indices have been aggregated
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()  # create an empty df for the return data
    for index, ele in enumerate(df['a']):  # iterate over the input df
        if ele and index > last:  # if the element is True and hasn't been aggregated
            last = index + mask_len  # increment the index tracking
            new_df = new_df._append(df.loc[index:last])  # and collect the data
    return new_df


print(mask_dataframe(df, 2))

This returns:
        a
1    True
2   False
3    True
5    True
6   False
7    True
8    True
9   False
10  False


You could get the True indices with the distance of 3:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, False],
    }
)

indices = df.index[df['a'] == True].tolist()

groups = [indices[0]]
for i in range(1, len(indices)):
    if indices[i] - groups[-1] >= 3:
        groups.append(indices[i])

for idx in groups:
    end = min(idx + 3, len(df))
    print(df.iloc[idx:end])


Prints
       a
1   True
2  False
3   True
       a
5   True
6  False
7   True
        a
8    True
9   False
10  False


Another possible solution:
from itertools import accumulate

N = 3

# gets the indexes where each group starts
idx = np.unique(np.array(list(
    accumulate(df.a[df.a].index, lambda x, y:  y if (y - x) >= N else x)
    )))

# creates the index for all groups
[df.iloc[i: i + N] for i in idx]

Output:
[       a
 1   True
 2  False
 3   True,
        a
 5   True
 6  False
 7   True,
         a
 8    True
 9   False
 10  False]


This fails if the last chunk has less than 3 rows. You should use df.iloc[i: i + N]

Thanks, @mozway, for calling my attention to that detail. I have meanwhile updated my answer accordingly.

To create the groups, filter the dataframe, then filter again to skip over every other second True and reindex back.
g = (df.loc[df['a'], 'a']
     .iloc[::2]
     .reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
     .cumsum()
    )

groups = [val[:3] for name, val in df.groupby(g) if name != 0]

End result:
[       a
 1   True
 2  False
 3   True,
        a
 5   True
 6  False
 7   True,
         a
 8    True
 9   False
 10  False]


I think your solution is incorrect for N greater than 2. You can't vectorize this iterative process.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Example usage:
data = {
    'a': [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, True, False, False],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
'''
        a
0   False
1    True
2   False
3    True
4   False
5    True
6   False
7    True
8    True
9   False
10  False
'''
# Find indices where df['a'] is True
true_indices = np.flatnonzero(df['a'].values)

# Initialize the group column with NaNs
gr_column = np.full(len(df),np.nan)

current_gr = 0 

for idx in true_indices :
    if np.isnan(gr_column[idx]):
        end_idx = min(idx + 3 ,len(df))
        gr_column[idx:end_idx] = current_gr
        current_gr += 1
        
        
print(gr_column)#[nan  0.  0.  0. nan  1.  1.  1.  2.  2.  2.]
df['group'] = gr_column 

df = df.dropna().reset_index(drop=True)
print(df) 
'''
      a  group
0   True    0.0
1  False    0.0
2   True    0.0
3   True    1.0
4  False    1.0
5   True    1.0
6   True    2.0
7  False    2.0
8  False    2.0
'''

